# Pinout Wiring of f4 v3s plus flight controller

Tags: flight-controller, esc, betaflight, multirotor

I have a **f4 v3s Plus** flight controller.
I want to wire it to a 4-in-1 ESC using micro JST connectors.

There are 8 pins in my flight controller and 7pins in my ESC board.
I understand that there is one NC pin on flight controller that's the reason ESC has a pin less.

But I don't know the JST connector pinout diagram of **f4 v3s plus** flight controller, neither was I able to find it online, can some body help on this please.

Comment: For starters, do you have user manuals or documentation for both of those components you are trying to get to work together? If not, even some links would be helpful, especially for the 4 in 1 ESC.